# How to build a tree from a function that takes information about the parent node

Tags: haskell

I have a function that takes in some data and returns an array of values. I need to map a list of data onto a tree.

As I create the tree each call to my function requires three parameters:

- A character from the string
- The index of the character from the string
- Part of the output of the function for the node's parent (or zero for the root)

For the sake of argument let's say I have:

```hs
input = "ABC"

func :: (Char, Int, Int) -> [(Char, Int, Int)]
func ('A', 1,    0) = [('Q', 1, 1243)]
func ('B', 2, 1243) = [('D', 2, 7512), ('R', 2, 8253)] -- 1243 taken from above
func ('C', 3, 7512) = [('E', 3, 2765)]
func ('C', 3, 8253) = [('Z', 3, 9836)]
```

Which would map to a tree like:

```
    ('Q', 1243)
     /       \
('D',7512)  ('R',8253)
    |         |
('E',2765)  ('Z',9836)
```

The first two parameters are fine, I can get those before building the list:

```hs
input `zip` [1..]
```

I'm not sure how to go about getting the third parameter though, since I only know the value for the root node (which will be zero) before I start building the tree. Am I going to have to learn about Monads?

Note: I'm completely new to Haskell and to Functional Programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you're after?

```
import Data.Tree

buildForest :: String ->
               ((Char, Int, Int) -> [(Char, Int, Int)]) ->
               Forest (Char, Int)
buildForest input children = go input 1 0
    where
        go []     _ _ = []
        go (x:xs) i n = map transform (children (x,i,n))
            where
                transform (y,_,n') = Node (y,n') (go xs (i+1) n')
```

Then with your example you'd call it like `buildForest "ABC" func`.

(Code untested, but if it's wrong you should still be able to use the general approach.)

Comment: Very nice! Thanks very much!